# Set Default Value for hidden field

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a hidden field where i save a value when button is clicked. But on page load there is no value assigned to it. I need to know how to set default value of hidden field.

I am saving a string in hidden field when button is clicked and then access it in a JS function. But on page load the JS function return Undefined value error as the value of hidden field is not set on page load.

```
 function Confirm() {
 var nom = document.getElementById('hdNomValue').Value;
 if (nom != "") 
  {
      // logic here 
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Is it in MVC application?

Comment: Or assign a value attribute to hidden field like <input type="hidden" value="myDefault">

Comment: No. ASP.NET with vb

Comment: @ bhanu.cs . I assigned it a value but not working

Comment: please check viewstate property of hiddenfield Or page

Comment: Ok fine .How did you form your hidden field using razor or as an  normal html element?

Comment: its normal html element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this

```
if (nom !== "" && nom !== undefined)
```

so, your code should be rewritten as below

```
function Confirm() {
     var nom = document.getElementById('hdNomValue').Value;
     if (nom !== "" && nom !== undefined)
     {
         // logic here 
     } 
}
```

Comment: yes, we can do it also this way, with !=="", I'll edit my answer, thanks

Comment: @FlyingGambit : what does that mean ?

Comment: @Abdul, replace your if with that above and it will work, because the code within the if branch will be executed only if nom is properly set

Comment: @Abdul the `!=` does not check for type while `!==` does, it just a good practice to use `!==` .   `"" == false` this returns true while `"" === false` returns false

Comment: Great Thanks @ddb and Flying Gambit.

Comment: Guys, it's value NOT Value. create a big problem sometimes. v is small

Answer (score 2):

You can simply try with this

```
function Confirm() {
    var nom = document.getElementById('hdNomValue').Value;
    if (nom) {
        // logic here 
    }
}
```

So `if(nom)` will return true only when it has non-blank value. It'll return *false*  if it is `""` or *`undefined`*

Now the next thing, you need to make sure about the `Id` of the element. If you are using the asp.net hidden field with `runat="server"` then Id would be different than what are you expecting. So to make sure that Id remains same as you've given in asp.net markup, use `ClientIdMode="Static"`

Comment: its simple and better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this:

```
if (nom != "" || nom != undefined) {
    //Your Logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here for only text,password fields in html only you can give a default value attribute .But in the case of html

```
<input type="hidden" value="">
```

element the value would not be assigned by default.

If you want to use a hidden field with a default value use a text field with the property of display:none like

```
<input type="text" style="display:none" value="Default">
```

Or else if you are determined to use the hidden element only then you can go for a javascript based check solution like

```
 var nom = document.getElementById('hdNomValue').Value;
if (nom != "" || nom != undefined) 
  {

  }
```

Answer (score -2):

what are you using jquery or javascript, if u are using jquery you may try to use

```
var nom = $('#hdNomValue').val();
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".